# Fluent NHibernate executes single-row-selects on thousands of objects to link to parents

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The following is a simplification of my problem domain. We have a series of **Trades**, that each gets a record in **Valuations** every business day.

We filter our **Valuations** List used for a specific day, but to populate the **Trade** against each of the **Valuation** rows, NHibernate fires single row selects on the **Trades** table for around 50k rows in the valuation table. How can I change this so NHibernate does a single select on the Trade table?

```
CREATE TABLE Trades
(   TradeId         INT
,   InstrumentType  VARCHAR(20)
,   TradeDate       DATETIME

,   PRIMARY KEY
(   TradeId )   )

CREATE TABLE Valuations
(   TradeId         INT
,   ValueDate       DATETIME
,   PresentValue    NUMERIC(12,4)

,   PRIMARY KEY
(   TradeId
,   ValueDate   )   )
```

.

```
class Trade
{
    public int TradeId;
    public string InstrumentType;
    public DateTime TradeDate;
}

class Valuation
{
    public int TradeId;
    public DateTime ValueDate;
    public double PresentValue;
    public Trade Trade;
}
```

.

```
class ValuationMap : ClassMap<Valuation>
{
    public ValuationMap()
    {
        WithTable("Valuations");
        UseCompositeId()
            .WithKeyProperty(x => x.ValueDate)
            .WithKeyProperty(x => x.TradeId);

        Map(x => x.PresentValue);

        References(x => x.Trade, "TradeId")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.None()
            .NotFound.Ignore()
            .FetchType.Join();
    }
}

class TradeMap : ClassMap<Trade>
{
    public TradeMap()
    {
        WithTable("Trades");

        Id( x => x.TradeId );

        Map(x => x.InstrumentType);
        Map(x => x.TradeDate);
        Map(x => x.Valuations);
    }
}
```

.

```
public List<Valuation> GetValuations(DateTime valueDate)
{
    return (from p in _nhibernateSession.Linq<Valuation>()
            where p.ValueDate == valueDate
            select p).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at batch fetching. This is quoted from the [Nhib manual](http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:D5O72SIzQSIJ:www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/performance.html+nhibernate+batching&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) - actually google's cache as the site seems to be down for maintenance atm:

> Imagine you have the following
>   situation at runtime: You have 25 Cat
>   instances loaded in an ISession, each
>   Cat has a reference to its Owner, a
>   Person. The Person class is mapped
>   with a proxy, lazy="true". If you now
>   iterate through all cats and get the
>   Owner of each, NHibernate will by
>   default execute 25 SELECT statements,
>   to retrieve the proxied owners. You
>   can tune this behavior by specifying a
>   batch-size in the mapping of Person:

```
<class name="Person" lazy="true" batch-size="10">...</class>
```

> NHibernate will now execute only three
>   queries, the pattern is 10, 10, 5. You
>   can see that batch fetching is a blind
>   guess, as far as performance
>   optimization goes, it depends on the
>   number of unitilized proxies in a
>   particular ISession.